# I have to pass paramater in url form send mail but line feed is not working in android

Tags: android, email

i could be happy if some one give me a solution,here i passed parameter in URL for sending an mail but line feed encoding code %0D and %0A not working.please help me.

stuff is

page_id=93&emailID=abcd@xyz.com&phoneNo=&subject=I Need Help - Safety Request via iHope&body=From: hh via iHope%0AMessage: I need help, call 911.%0AI am here: http://bit.ly/1qWrgfT%0AGPS Location appears to be: %0A-35, qwert qwerty yuioop, asdfghh, vfgrt poiuyt-%0A-380020%0A&from=From iHope support

Comment: can you post the code please

Comment: Could it be that you're using Unix-style line terminator (%0A) instead of Windows-style ones (%0D%0A)? Also, as Alexander pointed out, make sure to encode the entire URL for non-safe characters.

Comment: i have to try both %0D%0A or %0A but its not working line feed to received mail.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell us more about how this link is used? I see it's not a `mailto:` URL, so I suppose you send this over to a web service or something. If that's the case, any chance you can debug the receiving end?

Comment: yes, i got the whole mail in one string,but i want to mail in formatted text but line feed not working.

Comment: So is this an URL you send in a web request (i.e. http://example.org/some-service?page_id=...)? If it is, does the receiving end handle line breaks at all?

Comment: Yes URL is this,here i want receiving out put like this 
I need help, call 911
I am here: http://bit.ly/1qWrgfT
GPS Location appears to be:
35, Shidhnath Mahadev Mandir Marg, Premchand Nagar Society, Satellite Ahmedabad, Gujarat-

**Just Like**

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 3986, [section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1):

> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
> component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
> allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
> component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
> triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
> hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
> example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
> "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
> character (SP).  Section 2.4 describes when percent-encoding and
> decoding is applied.
>
> ```
>   pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
> ```

So, %D%A is incorrect. %0D%0A is correct.

According to your edit, if you use percent-encoding, you should encode the whole URI, including spaces and the rest. not only CR/LF chars. See [this post][2] on how to encode URL.